# How to I serialize an array of boolean?

Tags: java, arrays, serialization, boolean

I have an object that is defined as serialisable:

```
public class Tento3DToken implements java.io.Serializable
{
    private int idToken;
    private int dimension;
    private boolean[][][] bitmap;
    private String authorisedBy;
    private int runNumber;

    public Tento3DToken( int d, String a, int r)
    {
        dimension = d;
        authorisedBy = a;
        runNumber = r;
        bitmap = new boolean[d][d][d];
        idToken = 0;
    }
```

When this object is written to an ObjectOutputStream using WriteObject all the variable values are written to the output file except for the bitmap. How can serialise the bitmap?

Comment: What do you mean? How have you diagnosed this problem?

Comment: Can't reproduce, of course: https://ideone.com/OAhckQ. So voting to close.

Comment: I diagnosed the problem by looking at the output file for the serialisation with a binary file viewer. The file should have been about 400K long if all the content had been saved but it was only 40K. When checked all the values had been saved except for the values held by bitmap.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently a boolean array is not serialisable. Have solved the problem by making the bitmap transient and copying the array into a BitSet and serialising that.